# Asp .Net Identity 2 OAuth via Google+ error in production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, google-oauth, asp.net-identity-2

I am getting the problem when I use Asp .Net Identity 2 connect Google+. Currently, my website connect Google+ via OAuth API 2 and use Claim Identity store some information of users. I was setup fine in running localhost with https. But the problem appear when I deploy my website into production server. After use accept to provide permission for my website to get his information, Google+ callback my website with url /signin-google. And after that, ASP .Net MVC automatically redirect to `ExternalCallBack` action but it is get error `?error=access_denied`. I have capture the network and see information below:

In url callback signin-google:

`signin-google?state=nNABsQBmwoPILh1mViOUIqzDcxQIS3HVZx2jtrSYCwd-ifMn4bDgBV1H1qdewFZx5Lz1c35ZZEpUem9jDTUrKlzWDuV-MwTQ3Tesx66PEjWdQQHo0QPJHX_bRMHqgN-Ad1whLs4iUyUSCH39oeTvYg3Cx6O0_v7Sc5GaUujHgr6xW1jw8EImhWJgnFGXgkAjD5hOtr7RoYO23xJyw0AIyuWnyx1gInJndWKvL-eqWPD9BtRaNe3nhWF5NGEG_2Ir&code=4/OEwsZCeeDPKrN5Dls3Uu-Q0wacdMqlhdbb8B1P__8X8.MmSgAQ_-cmIRgrKXntQAax20FxCmlQI`

`Asp.Net.Collrelation.Google nXgdr60bDh6tfivnvc6NA6ubz1K9zwjOqgrBBQgsitE`

In URL callback external-login:

`external-login-callback?error=access_denied`

Hope you help me.

*Edit:
This is my code in Startup.Config.cs

```
 var googleOpt = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "xxxxxxxxpm0il.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxx",
            Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("GoogleAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                        return Task.FromResult(o);
                    }
            }
        };
        googleOpt.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
        googleOpt.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read");
        googleOpt.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOpt);
```

And in my account controller I use default code of Asp .Net MVC 5.2

Comment: Did you give permissions for your app to access Google+ API on app configuration page on Google?

Comment: Yes, I am sure open Google+ API on app configuration. But I considers about register my public domain and SSL for Google+. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Because I am experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and had to enable the Google+ API in the Google Developer Console.

[image]

If this is turned off, it will not work. As soon as I turned it on, everything was fine.